# submitting multiple sql queries in php loop with html forms

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'd like to submit multiple sql queries using a prepared statement and html forms. So far what I have will produce the forms, each with their own submit button. The connection to the database and submission works fine but only the form data whos button is pushed is submitted.

code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$sql = "describe indian_river_coffee;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$products = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0]."<br>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $insertedValues = $row[0];
    print($insertedValues)."<br>";
    ?>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
    <input name="submit" type="number" id="submit" value="submit">
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "insert into 
    indian_river_coffee 
    (". $insertedValues .") values (?);")){


        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST['submit']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

For example 3, 16, and 17 are put into the forms. If I push the submit button for 16 the value 16 is inserted three times into each column instead of 3, 16, 17 respectively.

I am very new to this and very open to changing the way I attack this problem.